# List selector not working properly

Tags: android, listview

In my application i am using a navigation drawer with list view.Now what i want is that when user selects a list item the color of the list item should change and also it should remain selected.With some research i am able to change the list item to desired color but it does not remains selected.

List selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/pink" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/pink" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/pink" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

</selector>
```

ListView.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_weight="3">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_nav_items"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:paddingBottom="05dp"></ListView>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Code onItemClick

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



        lvNavItems.setItemChecked(position, true);
        lvNavItems.setSelection(position);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(fragContainer);


    }
```

DrawerClass

```
public class NavigationDrawerFrag extends MasterFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private View view;
    private View fragContainer;

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private List<NavItems> listNavItems;
    private int[] icons = new int[]{R.drawable.ic_home_r, R.drawable.ic_profile, R.drawable.ic_celebrities, R.drawable.ic_verify, R.drawable.ic_about_us, R.drawable.ic_tc, R.drawable.ic_home, R.drawable.ic_home, R.drawable.ic_cancellation, R.drawable.ic_logout};
    private int[] iconsColored = new int[]{R.drawable.ic_home, R.drawable.ic_profile_r, R.drawable.ic_celebrities_r, R.drawable.ic_verify_r, R.drawable.ic_about_us_r, R.drawable.ic_tc_r, R.drawable.ic_home_r, R.drawable.ic_home_r, R.drawable.ic_cancellation_r, R.drawable.ic_logout_r};
    private String[] items;

    private ListView lvNavItems;
    private NavItemAdapter adapter;

    public NavigationDrawerFrag() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_drawer_frag, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public void setUp(DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar, int fragId) {

        fragContainer = getActivity().findViewById(fragId);

        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                drawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        lvNavItems = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_nav_items);
        items = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.NavItems);

        adapter = new NavItemAdapter(getActivity(), getListItems());
        lvNavItems.setAdapter(adapter);

        lvNavItems.setItemChecked(2, true);
        lvNavItems.setSelection(2);

        lvNavItems.setOnItemClickListener(this);


    }


    public List<NavItems> getListItems() {

        listNavItems = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < icons.length && i < items.length; i++) {

            NavItems navItems = new NavItems(items[i], icons[i]);
            listNavItems.add(navItems);

        }

        return listNavItems;
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


        CommonFunctions.replaceFragment(getActivity(), new ProfileFrag(), true);
        lvNavItems.setItemChecked(position, true);
        lvNavItems.setSelection(position);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(fragContainer);


    }
}
```

Custom list item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_nav_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_nav_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv_nav_icon"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_nav_icon"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="@dimen/regular" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

please do help me out where i went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume after click on any item you close the drawer and show some screen. When drawer is closed listview resets itself and re-render it when drawer is opened again.

Solution would be to save the selected index and in `getView` method you set the desired bg color on the item for that index.

1. Create a class level variable

   ```
   public static int NAV_CURR_SELECTION = 2; // you have used 2 in init()
   ```
2. Add this

   ```
   NAV_CURR_SELECTION = position;
   ```

   in `onItemClick()` method
3. Now, add these lines in `onDrawerOpened()`

   ```
   lvNavItems.setItemChecked(NAV_CURR_SELECTION, true);
   lvNavItems.setSelection(NAV_CURR_SELECTION);
   ```

**Edit**: Rather than using the two lines mentioned above in `onDrawerOpened()` do this. (Only change step 3. 1 and 2 need to remain same)

```
View v = lvNavItems.getChildAt(NAV_CURR_SELECTION);
v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00); // or whatever color you need
```

Comment: see i have updated it,please do help me out.Thanks :)

Comment: i did as u said but still no success

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference your selector:

Do

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/yourSelector"
```

instead of

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: tried but still the color comes but doesnt gets selected

Comment: Can you apply the selector to the background of each row instead?

Comment: i did tat aslo, see my post

Answer (score 0):

```
  <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_nav_items"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/listselector"
            android:paddingBottom="05dp"></ListView>
```